# GNU Make: шаблонное правило срабатывает только на первом файле

Tags: makefile, gnumake

Имеется Makefile:

```
ROOT_DIR = $(PWD)
BUILD_DIR = $(ROOT_DIR)/build
CXX = g++ 

SOURCES = $(wildcard $(ROOT_DIR)/*.cc)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.cc, %.o, $(subst $(ROOT_DIR), $(BUILD_DIR), $(SOURCES)))

$(OBJS) : $(SOURCES)
    @echo $< $@
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $<

all: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $? $<

clean:
    rm $(BUILD_DIR)/*o

print : $(ROOT_DIR)/*.cc
    @echo "OBJS" $(OBJS)
    @echo "SOURCES" $(SOURCES)
    @echo "@" $@
    @echo "<" $<
    @echo "^" $^
    @echo "*" $*
```

И каталог, в котором исходники:

```
build  main.cc  Makefile  smb1.cc  smb1.h  smb1_tr.cc
```

При вызове правила `$(OBJS) : $(SOURCES)` оно срабатывает только на первом файле списка.

Также вообще не срабатывает, если написать `$(OBJS) : %.cc`
Пишет что нету правила для сборки пререквизита. (Для примера попробуйте заменить символ `*` на `%` в правиле print.)

Что я делаю не так?

```
GNU Make 4.1
```

Можете скачать тут весь каталог: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/r-wId25734YCwA

Comment: Может надо `make all` запустить?

Comment: По умолчанию `make` собирает первую цель в файле. В вашем файле это как раз первый файл из `$(OBJ)`

Comment: @AlexeyTen Теперь он трижды выполняет сборку, но одного и того же исходного файла.

Comment: Ну у вас в целом кривой файл. Сейчас попробую поправить

Comment: Обновил ответ. PS ваш main.cc не компилируется =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цель по умолчанию это [первая цель](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Goals) в `makefile`.

Цель `all` [рекомендуется](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Standard-Targets) делать целью по умолчанию. Для этого она должна быть либо первой в файле, либо можно использовать специальную переменную `.DEFAULT_GOAL`:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
```

В целом у вас очень странный makefile. Непонятно зачем нужет `ROOT_DIR`, мы и так в каталоге с исходниками.
Правило `$(OBJS) : $(SOURCES)` означает что каждый `.o`-файл зависит от **всех** `.cc`-файлов. Вряд ли вы хотели именно так. Тем не менее, в рецепте к этому правилу вы использовали переменную `$<` которая означает «первый из списка зависимостей», т.е. у вас для любого `.o`-файла всегда компилировался первый файл из списка.

Я бы написал так:

```
# Задаём дефолтную цель
.DEFAULT_GOAL = all

# ROOT_DIR не нужен, сборка всегда запускается в текущем каталоге
BUILD_DIR = build
CXX = g++

SOURCES := $(wildcard *.cc)
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cc, %.o, $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(SOURCES)))

# создаём папку
$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

# Правило для сборки build/FOO.o из FOO.cc
# https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o : %.cc | $(BUILD_DIR)
    @echo $< $@
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $<

$(BUILD_DIR)/prog: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJS)

all: $(BUILD_DIR)/prog

clean:
    rm -r $(BUILD_DIR)
```

Comment: Хорошо, но я уже написал свой рабочий Makefile, который тоже работает: https://pastecode.io/s/6qnp7d9fy7

Comment: К тому, чтобы написать `$(OBJS) : $(SOURCES)` меня довела вторая проблема.